# Is there a way to call a function in a parent class in java?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a base class for my androids screen, it is has a list control.  Is there a way for when the base class's  onListItemClick gets called, saying a list item was selected.  It could call a function in the parent class??

Code:

```
public class cHome extends cBase {
String[] MyItems={ 
        "Gate Directions",
        "Food & Beverges",
        "Shjops",
        "Banking",
        "Official Agencies",
        "Amenities & Services",
        "Restrooms"
        };

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle, MyItems);
//  Display=MyItems;
}
```

Code:

```
public class cBase extends ListActivity  {

String[] items={"CASUAL","DRESSES","CAREER","OUTWEAR","FOOTWEAR",
        "JEWELRY","ACCESSORIES"};
String[] Display;


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle, String[] items2) {
     Display=items2;
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.baselayout);
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));
//  selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

// set values in header
     // set header
     TextView mFlight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idFlyerFlightNumber);
     mFlight.setText( cGlobals.mFlightNumber);     

     TextView mDes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idFlyerDestanation);
     mDes.setText( cGlobals.mDestanation);

}


class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Activity context;

    IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, Display);

        this.context=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

        label.setText(Display[position]);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

//      String[] items={"CASUAL","DR ESSES","CAREER","OUTWEAR","FOOTWEAR",
    //          "JEWELRY","ACCESSORIES"};

        switch(position)
        {
        case 0:
    //      icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.formobile_items);
            break;

        case 1:
        //  icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fashion_dress);
            break;

        case 2:
//          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fashion_career);
            break;

        case 3:
//          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fashion_outwear);
            break;

        case 4:
    //      icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fashion_footwear);
            break;

        case 5:
//          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fashion_jewelry);
            break;

        case 6:
//          icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fashion_accessories);
            break;


        }
        return(row);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should indicate where and what method you want to call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `onListItemClick` in your child class and just call `super.onListItemClick` on it. Or don't override it and `onListItemClick` method of base class will be called automatically when item in the list selected.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question, what you want is to have a way for the base class to invoke a method on a class that extends it.

One way to accomplish this is to establish a "contract" that dictate what methods an extending class **must** implement.  You do that with either an abstract class or an interface.  The base class then knows what methods WILL be available to it when a class extends it, and can make the call.

```
public abstract class BaseThing {

   public void foo() {
       bar();
   }

   public abstract bar();
}
```

then:

```
public ParentThing extends BaseThing {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println( "Hey, look at that.  It worked!" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you, I did not know this about java, I learned something new!!!!! Sort of learning java as I work on projects.